# gdb with qemu prints wrong values for variables

Tags: gdb, qemu, gdbserver

I am using qemu 32-bit x86 to test out my kernel, and I am trying to debug it using gdb but I am having two problems

1. whenever I use the `next` command gdb executes it like `step` and just steps-into the sub routine which makes debugging very hard
2. printing out any variable show absurdly wrong value (ex: `int i = 0;` shows 792080624)

I am running 6.3.6-arch1-1 and GNU gdb (GDB) 13.1

Answer (score 0):

I solved it by using `qemu-system-i386` instead of `qemu-system-x86_64`, but I do not totally understand why